# Clearing duplicates from an Excel 2007 sheet

Tags: performance, vba, excel

This is the original code I had for removing duplicates from a sheet:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call Hide_Columns_Swivel

End Sub
```

I added a section to this code (see below) that clears contents of fake empty cells. But now the code takes up to 15 seconds to run. It works as it is suppose to, just really slowly.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim usedrng As Range

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes

    For Each usedrng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If usedrng.Value = "" Then
            usedrng.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call Hide_Columns_Swivel

End Sub
```

I need help making this more efficient as I do not know enough about VBA to do that. All assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a purpose to clearing the contents of empty cells?

Comment: @Comintern Yes. I run a conditional format code from the worksheet object that checks AD2:AD2000. If we insert a date into this column for a row, it changes the text in the row to green. The problem was that the remove duplicates code was adding null values to the cells. I would test this by pasting the data in and adding a date to AD for any of the rows with new data. The change would occur. But, once we ran the remove duplicates, all the rows would change to green text. So I added this code to clear out the fake empties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have played around with the code by using suggestions posted here, and also from other sources. I have made the following changes to the Remove_Duplicates sub:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Call CTEGT

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call Hide_Columns_Swivel

End Sub
```

I added `Call CTEGT` which is the following code:

```
Sub CTEGT()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = 1000 'change this to the last row
Application.EnableEvents = True

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Trim(Range("AD" & i).Value) = "" Then Range("AD" & i).ClearContents
    Next

End Sub
```

Over the last few days of new data being added, it was taking exponentially longer to run the code. This new iteration is now almost instant.

Thanks for all the contributions. I hope this assists anyone with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to get zero-length strings left after reverting formulas (that may have resulted in `""` ) to their values, the quickest way is to spin through the columns and apply a quick Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish to each.

```
Dim c As Long
With worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion  `<~~ set to the desired range of one or more columns
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(c), _
                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        Next c
    End With
End With
```

This process will take zero-length strings and make then truly blank cells. This is an important step in preppinga worksheet for direct non-CSV import to MS-SQL.

Comment: How does this work? Loop through the columns and go `.TextToColumns` on each with the destination as the original column you just performed this on (overwrite). Would this retain cells in the column that have a non-blank value? Maybe I'm thrown off by the `FieldInfo` argument, but I can't seem to deconstruct this in my head.

Comment: While a zero-length string is retained when reverting formulas to their results (e.g. `.cells = .value` ), looping through a TextToColumns reevaluates the values, discarding zero-length strings. You can do the same thing with `dim arr as variant: arr = cells.value: cells = arr` but that can be expensive in large blocks of data; better to take it one column at a time. The **FieldInfo** parameter is required but simply used as *General* (see [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) ). Cells with values will not have their values changed.

Comment: Ah, clever! Thanks! Would it end up repopulating with empty strings once excel recalculates the formulas?

Comment: Well, it isn't going to do anything unless the formulas were removed in the first place. That was implied in my first sentence. You have to revert formulas to their result value (which may leave zero-length strings) before you can remove the zero-length strings.

Answer (score 2):

Using Replace will convert non-blank, zero-length-string cells to truly blank cells.

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").UsedArea
  'First convert zero-length cells to a unique value
  .Replace("", "MontgomeryBurns")
  'Then convert all of those cells to Empty cells
  .Replace("MontgomeryBurns", "")
End With
```

Comment: Why not set them to `vbnullstring` instead of `""` again?